# Remove prefix from a namespace of a xsd file

Tags: c#, xsd, xml-namespaces

I am new to XSD.

```
<xs:schema id="test"
    targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/test.xsd"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns:bb="http://tempuri.org/test.xsd"        
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>
```

and the fields are as follows

bb:name

bb:age

bb:location

I need to remove the 'bb' from namespace so that it becomes xmlns="........." as well as I need to remove 'bb:' from the field name as well using C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
xsdString.Replace("xmlns:bb=", "xmlns=").Replace("<bb:", "<").Replace("</bb:", "</")
```

Comment: thanks its working but I am using 'XDocument' to load the xsd file. So, is that possible to replace using Xdocument?

Comment: First you can load your xsd into a string, replace what you need, then load it into XDocument - [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.parse.aspx)